# How to allow an image to expand into SwiftUI safe area without the bottom shifting

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, how can we tell an image to extend itself across a safe area above it, but without affecting the bottom positioning of the image?

I have a design where a banner image needs to cover the top 200 pixels of the usable device area (ie the top 200 pixels that do not include the safe area). I can achieve that effect easily, if I disregard the safe-area, using the following code:

```swift
struct SafeAreaTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("Banner")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(height: 200)
                .clipped()
//                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I add the [`.ignoresSafeArea()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ignoressafearea(_:edges:)) to the `Image`, because I also want my image to cover the safe-area, then yes, the image extends to through the safe-area, but it also moves up by the height of the safe-area, exposing parts of the screen that should have the banner in them. I don't know how to compensate for the additional space that's opened up by `.ignoresSafeArea()`. It is no longer covering the 200 pixels of banner area that I needed covered. Suggestions?

I don't mind if the image is scaled up to fit in the larger area.

Comment: Well, for starters, don't set `.frame(height: 200)` - that in combination with `.ignoresSafeArea()` means that image will shift up by safe area height. If you want the image to extend 200px + safe area, then use `GeometryReader`'s `safeAreaInsets` to add height of safe area to `200`. This is one way to do it.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! However, I found I needed to put the Image in an overlay so that an empty gap with height of safeArea height is not inserted into the layout. Would you like to write this up as an answer? If you prefer, I could do it.

Comment: Hey @timbretimbre, I haven't heard back from you, so I'm going to go ahead and write this up in a couple of days unless you tell me you'd rather I didn't. Thanks again for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timbretimbre suggested in the comments that the [safeAreaInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy/safeareainsets) member of the [GeometryProxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) structure that you are given when using a [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader), will give you the measurement you need to adjust your image height to compensate for the upward shift.

I have spelled this out in code below, first attempting to simply add the inset height to the image height (try the "Inset Only" option), but that results in a gap (with height of overlay inset) being created between the image and the rest of the layout.

Then, to overcome the gap, I'm suggesting the technique of putting the original image into an overlay (the "Inset & Overlay" option), so that the height adjustment doesn't impact the original layout.

```
enum SafeAreaStrategy : Hashable {
    case ignore, useInsetOnly, useInsetAndOverlay
}

struct SafeAreaTest: View {
    @State private var strategy = SafeAreaStrategy.ignore
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                switch strategy {
                case .ignore:
                    Image("Banner")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                        .clipped()
                        .border(.red)
                case .useInsetOnly:
                    Image("Banner")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(height: 200 + geo.safeAreaInsets.top)
                        .clipped()
                        .border(.red)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .border(.green)
                case .useInsetAndOverlay:
                    Color(.clear)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                        .overlay {
                            Image("Banner")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(height: 200 + geo.safeAreaInsets.top)
                                .clipped()
                                .border(.red)
                                .ignoresSafeArea()
                        }
                }
                Picker("Safe Area Strategy", selection: $strategy) {
                    Text("Leave Blank").tag(SafeAreaStrategy.ignore)
                    Text("Inset Only").tag(SafeAreaStrategy.useInsetOnly)
                    Text("Inset & Overlay").tag(SafeAreaStrategy.useInsetAndOverlay)
                }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
            }
        }
    }
}
```